# Optimization Exercise: Minimizing Absolute Differences

Tags: statistics, optimization

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n$ be real numbers, $n = 2N + 1 \geq 3$. Find the solution of the following minimization problem:

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2 x_i| \rightarrow \min_{\beta_1, \beta_2}$

My idea:

We consider two cases: when $ \beta_2 \neq 0 $ and when $ \beta_2 = 0 $.

#### Case 1: $ \beta_2 \neq 0 $

The partial derivatives of the objective function are:

$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1} |y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i| = -\text{sign}(y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i) $
$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_2} |y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i| = -x_i \text{sign}(y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i) $

Setting the derivatives equal to zero gives the system of equations:

$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} -\text{sign}(y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i) = 0 $
$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} -x_i \text{sign}(y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2x_i) = 0 $

This system needs to be solved for $ \beta_1 $ and $ \beta_2 $.

#### Case 2: $ \beta_2 = 0 $

In this case, the minimization problem becomes:

$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |y_i - \beta_1| \to \min_{\beta_1} $

The solution for $ \beta_1 $ is the median of the set $ \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\} $.

Is my problem solving method correct and if yes how could I finish it?

Comment: I think the proper condition for case 1 is not $\beta_2\neq 0$ but $y_i - \beta_1 - \beta_2 x_i \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Your case 2 could produce a range of medians between $y_{(n/2)}$ and $y_{(1+n/2)}$ if $n$ is even.  There may be circumstances where your case 1 also produces ranges

Comment: You can linearize the objective and solve it using linear programming solver. I doubt that it has a closed form optimal solution except for the second case, mentioned above by @Henry. As $n$ is odd, the optimal solution for the second case is the median $y_{(N+1)}$. It is known as  least absolute deviations regression: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations